# How to parse PE file dont use API

Tags: c++, c, parsing, portable-executable

I learned how to parse PE files according to this [article](https://ired.team/miscellaneous-reversing-forensics/pe-file-header-parser-in-c++)

In this article, they use existing APIs and structs

Now I want to rewrite a program by myself, without calling api and available structs.Read some infomation of PE file look like image below

[image]

I want to ask is the algorithm or how the developer created them. Can give me some hints or link ?
i need use fread () and fseek () to read one bye one, right??

Thank you

edit : oh, it i curiosity and wanna learn more

Comment: Why do you wan to do it yourself? Is it just as a learning experience or curiosity (which is fine, but please add a note in your question about it)? Or is there some other problem that you think rewriting it yourself will solve? Typically, something like this isn't trivial, and depending on what you will use it for the chances of making mistakes is higher if you write it yourself than if you use existing API's.

Comment: Thank dude, just curiosity and wanna learn more. U can give me some hints about it ?

Comment: The program in the article doesn't use any existing API but only existing structs that reflect the different parts of the PE header. Most you need to know is in the article. You can find more information about PE headers by googling things such as  "Microsoft PE header".

Comment: This question is too broad for the site as it stands. Go ahead and try it out, and start a specific question if/when you run into any difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches in general:

- If you are certain the binary format will always be used with the same binaries on the same architecture, you can read the data into memory and treat it as a "pointer to struct". This is very probably how the original authors implemented it. The downside is that this code is not portable across architectures and even compiler flags (padding in structs, alignment, ...).
- The other, more portable approach, is to read the data entry by entry. This results in a significant amount of code that closely resembles the structure, but it is portable and versatile. These kinds of binary file formats often evolve together with the code that uses them, and you can trivially insert versions and if statements to alter the way these are read.

  For example, using the [stream API](https://github.com/scummvm/scummvm/blob/master/common/stream.h) of a well-known open source project, you would read the first few entries as follows:

```
Common::SeekableReadStream * s = ...;
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER d = new IMAGE_DOS_HEADER;
d->e_magic = s->readUint16LE();
d->e_cblp = s->readUint16LE();
d->e_cp = s->readUint16LE();
...
```

As a middle ground between the two approaches, I have come to like [Kaitai struct](https://kaitai.io), where you write a specification of the format in a declarative style and let its compiler generate the struct definition for you, along with code to read (and write!) these file formats.

Take a look at the corresponding excerpt from [their gallery](http://formats.kaitai.io/dos_mz/index.html):

```
  mz_header:
    seq:
      - id: magic
        size: 2
      - id: last_page_extra_bytes
        type: u2
      - id: num_pages
        type: u2
      - id: num_relocations
        type: u2
```